# IntelliJ IDEA Kotlin project unresolved reference: apache

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, apache-poi

I'm trying to run the following code:

```
import org.apache.poi.util.Units
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.Document
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.io.FileOutputStream

fun main(){
    val document = XWPFDocument()

    val jpegFile= File("C:\\pics\\img.jpg")
    val outputStream = FileOutputStream(File("C:\\200\\1.docx"))

    document.createParagraph().createRun().addPicture(FileInputStream(jpegFile),  Document.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG, jpegFile.name, Units.toEMU(500.0), Units.toEMU(500.0))

    document.write(outputStream)
    outputStream.close()
}
```

which utilizes the Apache POI library. I placed the extracted folders from the downloaded zip in the libs folder and added the folder as a library.

The IDE recognizes it and understands imports. However when I try to compile it, it fails to compile and I have these strange errors:

```
e: C:\Users\user\Exercism\kotlin\POIonkt\src\main\kotlin\kotlinc\bin\main.kt: (4, 12): Unresolved reference: apache
e: C:\Users\user\Exercism\kotlin\POIonkt\src\main\kotlin\kotlinc\bin\main.kt: (5, 12): Unresolved reference: apache
e: C:\Users\user\Exercism\kotlin\POIonkt\src\main\kotlin\kotlinc\bin\main.kt: (6, 12): Unresolved reference: apache
e: C:\Users\user\Exercism\kotlin\POIonkt\src\main\kotlin\kotlinc\bin\main.kt: (12, 20): Unresolved reference: XWPFDocument
e: C:\Users\user\Exercism\kotlin\POIonkt\src\main\kotlin\kotlinc\bin\main.kt: (18, 83): Unresolved reference: Document
e: C:\Users\user\Exercism\kotlin\POIonkt\src\main\kotlin\kotlinc\bin\main.kt: (18, 126): Unresolved reference: Units
e: C:\Users\user\Exercism\kotlin\POIonkt\src\main\kotlin\kotlinc\bin\main.kt: (18, 146): Unresolved reference: Units
```

Command line kotlinc gives the same errors. Please advice.

Thank you in advance!

Edited:

Using Intellij IDEA 2021.2.1

Edited2:
Added to main:

```
    System.setProperty("javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory", "com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.InputFactoryImpl");
    System.setProperty("javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory", "com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.OutputFactoryImpl");
    System.setProperty("javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory", "com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.EventFactoryImpl");
    System.setProperty("org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory", "com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.InputFactoryImpl");
    System.setProperty("org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory", "com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.OutputFactoryImpl");
    System.setProperty("org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory", "com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.EventFactoryImpl");
```

Added to dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.fasterxml:aalto-xml:1.0.0'
implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '5.0.0'
```

Comment: Do you use a build system? (e.g. Maven, Gradle) Where did you download the Jar file? I'd recommend you try adding this dependency with Maven.

Comment: @EgorKlepikov Jar files come from here https://poi.apache.org/download.html#POI-5.0.0
Using gradle. Tried adding dependency manually, no luck. Have no experience with Maven

Comment: If you're using Gradle try adding dependency as "implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '5.0.0'" to your build.gradle file.